# DOM scripting book

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a copy of [DOM Scripting](http://domscripting.com/) from couple of years ago, but unfortunately I have never used the book to learn DOM. I use some jquery here and there in my websites and I have no trouble understanding jquery. In what way will the book be useful to me, now that javascript frameworks like jquery are commonplace?

Comment: I think you should ask the author.

Comment: Do you understand what jQuery does under the hood?

Comment: @Matt Ball my friend, I must disagree with your decision to vote to close this one. It did sound a little like he was asking about the specific book, but he was actually asking whether it is worth it to read the book in order to understand the DOM. I wish *more* jQuery users would ask this. ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the underlying principles upon which the libraries are built will never hurt you, and I'd say is very important.

It will enable you to pick and chose where you want to use the DOM API directly vs. where to use library code.

Also, browser compliance is getting better, enabling you to depart from library code more easily if you so choose.

So I'd say that as you have time, go through the book. As you code in jQuery, you'll see different places where you can integrate the two.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is pretty much a cross-browser javascript DOM library; It simplifies the way people access a particular DOM element (using CSS selector) in comparison to using native DOM javascript API (using document.getElementById..etc).

the book will absolutely be helpful if you want to understand more about native javascript DOM and how they came up with all those useful jQuery features. I also want to add though, to make the most out of your jQuery experience, you may want to have deeper understanding in javascript...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not learn about javascript and web technologies in general, how will you ever be able to evaluate different design approaches, libraries or frameworks and choose those most suited to a particular task? Or will you just choose "what everyone else uses"?

By far the greatest effort in a non-trivial development project is design and testing, the time taken to do the actual code (regardless of whether you are using a published library, reuable code from a repository or starting from scratch) is becoming less and less (below 20% by some estimates). So put your effort into learning good design and the code will look after itself.

From the sample chapter of the referenced book, that seems to be the approach of the author. If the rest of the book is on a similar vein, you should read it.